# Count the number of years ago from a date

Tags: r

I have retrieved my birthday in the format 06/23/1993 from Facebook and I want to turn this birthday into my age.

This is the code I have so far:

```
install.packages("eeptools")
library(eeptools)

as.POSIXct(facebook$birthday, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin="1970-01-01")
as.Date(facebook$birthday, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

facebook$age <- floor(age_calc(facebook$birthday, units = "years"))
```

After the first 2 lines it returns this:

```
as.POSIXct(facebook$birthday, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin="1970-01-01")
#[1] "1993-06-23 CEST"
as.Date(facebook$birthday, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "1993-06-23"
```

After the last line I get this error:

> Error in age_calc(facebook$birthday, units = "years") : 
>     Both dob and enddate must be Date class objects

Would be much appreciated if anyone could help me out :)

Resolved!
Edit: I just forgot to insert as.Date in this last line:

```
facebook$age <- floor(age_calc(as.Date(facebook$birthday, units = "years"))
```

Comment: You need `format = "%m/%d/%Y"` (slashes, capital Y)

Comment: Also, use `as.Date` to convert to Date object.

Comment: Oh, and read this `?strftime` - quite useful ;-)

Comment: @jakub thanks for your response, as you can see in my edited question it has helped to solve the first issue, now I want to turn the data into a rounded age which is 23... do you (or anyone else) know how to fix the error?

Comment: btw after running the first 2 lines it is still a character if I run class(facebook$birthday), might have something to do with it

Comment: Have you actually stored the steps in a variable? Cause it looks like you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what fails. This is what I do and it works for me:

```
install.packages("eeptools")
library(eeptools)

date = "06/23/1993"
date = as.POSIXct(date, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin="1970-01-01")

floor(age_calc(as.Date(date), units = "years"))
#[1] 23
```

Or without the POSIXct conversion (as per G. Grothendieck's comment):

```
floor(age_calc(as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), units = "years"))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... The problem was that I didn't assign as.Data to a new object.. beginners mistake I guess :D

Comment: as.POSIXct(facebook$birthday, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin="1970-01-01")
facebook$birthday <- as.Date(facebook$birthday, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
class(facebook$birthday)
facebook$age <- floor(age_calc(facebook$birthday, units = "years"))

Comment: You always have to assign the result to a variable (the same or a new one) if you want to work with it further, otherwise it just gets printed out on the console but does not persist.

Comment: Right! Updated.